# gthumb won't start after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, gthumb

Trying to start gthumb after an upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 I get following error message:

> ** (gthumb:4351): CRITICAL **: 16:22:51.965: Could not load the mandatory extension 'cairo_io': Modul »cairo_io« konnte nicht geöffnet werden: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gthumb/extensions/libcairo_io.so: undefined symbol: heif_image_get_primary_height

> [1]+  Abgebrochen             (Speicherabzug geschrieben) gthumb

I first tried to reinstall the gthumb package - no change.
I reinstalled libcairo2 - to no avail.
Restarting the computer didn't bring about any changes either.
I then installed gthumb from PPA:ubuntuhandbook1 as described [here](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/09/gthumb-3-12-0-released-ppa-ubuntu/). There actually were updates for gthumb which had me hoping, but still the problem persists.

Any suggestions short of reinstalling Ubuntu?

installed Ubuntu version
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

GTHUMB version
$ gthumb --version
gthumb 3.12.2, Copyright © 2001-2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try re-installing libcairo2. I had a similar problem with a different program and that fixed it.

```
sudo apt-get install libcairo2 --reinstall
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. Sadly, I've already tried that (see original post) to no avail.